# How to create Items in Podio using podio-php?

Tags: php, podio

Podio's API documentation differs from podio-php's when it comes to creating new Items.

Based on [Podio's tutorial](https://developers.podio.com/examples/items), I would have to format each value according to its type, whereas [podio-php](https://podio-community.github.io/podio-php/items/) describes using `PodioItemFieldCollection` to handle that for you. I prefer the latter option, but I keep getting this error:

```
Invalid value "1" (string): Not a valid option
```

I don't see much difference in my code versus the example given by podio-php. What's causing this error?

```
$fields = new PodioItemFieldCollection(array(
    new PodioTextItemField(array("external_id" => "my-text-field", "values" => "FooBar")),
    new PodioProgressItemField(array("external_id" => "my-number-field", "values" => 75))
));    

$atts = array(
    'app' => new PodioApp($app_id), 
    'fields' => $fields
);

$item = new PodioItem($atts);
```

No errors caught up to here. But when I try to save...

```
$response   = $item->save();

Invalid value "1" (string): Not a valid option
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like you have a typo in $atts array: a quote before `app' =>` is missing.
But anyways, are you sure `$app_id` is set correctly? This is the only difference from the tutorial I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$app_id` was being passed in as a string. I've had this issue now with a few different ID values returned in an API response. I explicitly cast the value as an integer and the error went away:

```
$atts = array(
    'app'    => new PodioApp((int)$app_id), 
    'fields' => $fields
);
```